# .NET Identity Web Api correct reuse of DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I want to have one database connection per request. I'm trying to accomplish this by reusing my Identity `ApplicationDbContext`. I have defined `DbSet`'s for my application entities in this `ApplicationDbContext`. So this should be the only context I need for my entire application.

My `ConfigureAuth` method is configured to create one `ApplicationDbContext` per `OwinContext`.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   // db context and user manager use a single instance per request
   app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
   app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
   ....
}
```

In my API Controller I use the OwinContext to retrieve the context.

**SomeController**

```
private ApplicationDbContext _db;
public ApplicationDbContext DB
{
   get
   {
       if (_db == null)
       {
           _db = Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
           _db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
       }
       return _db;
   }
   private set
   {
       _db = value;
   }
}
```

So far so good. To monitor this behavior I implemented the `Dispose` method in my `ApplicationDbContext` class.

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Disposing ApplicationDbContext");
   base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Now I never see those disposing messages. Does this mean I have stale db connections ? As you may have noticed I disabled AutomaticProxy creation. Does this influence the lifecycle ? Is this a problem for Identity ?

I reasoned for myself I do not need a `dispose` method in my controllers to disposes the context because that's what the owin part will do for me.

Comment: are you running the Debug (and not the Release) build?

Comment: I am running the Debug build. Just double checked it. (I use the same type of debug info in de c'tor of ApplicationDbContext. The console tells me when an instance is created.)

Comment: @サモライ This question is indeed answered. Thank you.